# Sorting a list element alphabetically

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7

The data I load with the below code will end up in the following format:

```
new_list = [['1', '100', 'A', 'B,A'], ['2', '200', 'A', 'T'],
['3', '200', 'H', 'A,C'], ['4', '300', 'W', 'T'],
['5', '400', 'I', 'BABA,ABB'], ['6', '500', 'Q', 'LP,AL']]
```

What I want to achieve is sorting the last column alphabetically changing the list to:

```
new_list = [['1', '100', 'A', 'A,B'], ['2', '200', 'A', 'T'],
['3', '200', 'H', 'A,C'], ['4', '300', 'W', 'T'],
['5', '400', 'I', 'ABB,BABA'], ['6', '500', 'Q', 'AL,LP']]
```

However I don't know how to sort only a specified index in this list.
Should I split the last column on `,`?

Sample data:

```
# Data
# I
# don't
# need
1   100 982 A   B,A 41
2   200 982 A   T   42
3   200 982 H   C   43
4   300 982 W   T   43
5   400 982 I   BABA,ABB    44
6   500 982 Q   LP,AL   44
```

Loading the data:

```
filename = 'test.txt'

new_list = []

readFile = open(filename, 'r')
lines = readFile.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if not line[0].startswith('#'):
        linewords = line.split()
        new_list.append([linewords[0],
                        linewords[1],
                        linewords[3],
                        linewords[4]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

split it on ",", then sort, then join the list :

```
new_list.append([linewords[0],
                        linewords[1],
                        linewords[3],
                        ",".join(sorted(linewords[4].split(",")))])
```

Answer (score 0):

first split, then sort, last join. there may be more than one blank space, you can use regex split.

```
import re
p = re.compile(' +')

for line in lines:
    if line.startswith('#'):
        continue
    linewords = p.split(line)
    lastword = linewords[4].split(',')
    lastword.sort()
    new_list.append([linewords[0],linewords[1],linewords[3],','.join(lastword)])
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
def sort_last(inner_list):
    last = inner_list[-1].split(',')
    last.sort()
    last = ','.join(last)
    return inner_list[:-1] + [last]

new_list = [sort_last(l) for l in new_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[x[:-1]+[','.join(sorted(x[-1].split(',')))] for x in new_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
list2 = []

for level1 in new_list:
    _temp = []
    for level2 in level1:
        if "," in level2:
            _temp.append(sorted(level2.split(",")))
        else:
            _temp.append(level2)
    list2.append(_temp)

print list2
```